# change array value in php through array place

Tags: php

How to change or update array value in PHP through array number?

Example:

```
$array1 = array("cat","dog","mouse","dog");
```

I want to change the value of dog in the 2nd array only

Comment: what did you tried ?

Comment: `$array1[3] = "rat";` this is very very basic stuff....

Comment: Not sure why this question was upvoted

Comment: thank you, i'll try that. It will still work in json array?

Comment: @NikkoDelaCruz In php json is object not an array. Or probabely it is an associative array not a list like one.

Comment: This is not a "ask all questions on one page"-website. SO is meant as a knowledge bank. Replacing your question like this means this thread has no value in the future and should because of that be removed.

Comment: New questions go into a new post. I've rolled back your change, please do not do that again.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit :-**

To delete element use unset(arrayVar[key])

**For eg :-**
unset($array1[1]) - will delete the "mouse" at key/index 1 if you wish to delete 2nd occurance then use unset($array1[3])

**Original :-**

Explain your problem in more detail please !

What do you mean by 2nd array and where exactly is it ?

Do you mean to edit the 2nd occurance of "dog" in array ?
If so then it would be $array1[3]="someNewValue"

Comment: This has a possible solution, but is not really an answer.  It's better to use comments to ask clarifying questions.

Comment: @DSway he can't comment.

Comment: why $array1[3], isn't $array[1]?, the first dog in array

Answer (score 0):

Use [Variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php):

```
$a = 'array' . '1';
$$a[1] = 'doggg'; #value changed
$b = 'array' . '2';
$$b[1] = 'newDogg'; #value changed
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to remove 2 index then

```
$array1 = array('dog','mouse','cat','mouse');
 unset($array1[1]);
 print_r($array1);
```

Output

```
Array ( [0] => dog [2] => cat [3] => mouse )
```

//if you are looking for remvoing duplicate value then you can use array_unique

```
$result=array_unique($array1);

print_r($result);
```

Output

```
Array ( [0] => dog [1] => mouse [2] => cat )
```

Comment: isn't? Array ( [0] => dog [1] => cat [2] => mouse ). because the first mouse is already deleted?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you have to remove an element from an array, probably this will help.

```
array_splice( $array1, OFFSET, 1 );
```

replace OFFSET with the index you want to remove.

Comment: i want to delete it, not to replace it

Comment: array_splice will remove items, and also it will rearrange the array. I am sorry if this is not your requirement.